# sql - random select

Tags: sql

I have two tables. First : questions table : [idquestion, question] Second : answers table [idanswer, answer,points, idquestion] . I would like to select all questions in random order and all answers for questions in random order :

```
  Somethink like this :

          Question 5 : ans1, ans2, ans3,ans4
          Question 2 : ans3, ans4,ans1,ans2
          Question 3 : ans2, ans3,ans1,ans4
          ...
          Question 1 : ..
```

Please help

Sorry for my english

Comment: have you considered searching Stackoverflow first before posting?

Answer (score 2):

This may work on mysql:

```
SELECT question, answer FROM questTable LEFT JOIN ansTable ON questTable.idquestion = ansTable.idquestion
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

In any case random is not a common function, each SQL database have different syntax: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm

Comment: Thank you but your query give me one question and one answer but i would like to have all questions and all answers but answers for questions together

Comment: @RobertBednarowski Remove the `LIMIT 1`